# Shadow catcher casts light (?) on the floor

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, tracking

I'm using Cycles render to render footage with camera tracking and video in the background. I had marked "Shadow Catcher" under Ray Visibility in Cycles Settings in "Rendered" viewport view (SHIFT + Z) everything looks fine (but the video seems a little bit too dark) but when I render frame I can see this:

[image]

3D ground plane enlight the floor. How can I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

It's a problem in Compositor. Seems like by mistake you connected AO pass instead of Shadow pass of Background layer to Add node in Compositor. The same issue as yours:

[image]

And correct one:

[image]